# Does JavaScript support Unboxing or does it only support Autoboxing?

Tags: javascript

I know that JavaScript support Autoboxing (the automatic conversion from a primitive data type to its object counterpart), but does JavaScript also support Unboxing (the automatic conversion from an object to its primitive data type counterpart)?

Comment: "Autoboxing" is not really the correct term. Not in the sense of Java, at least where autoboxing can have serious implication for speed. Similarly "unboxing" isn't quite correct, either. There is *type coercion* but I wouldn't want to mix it with boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

> but does JavaScript also support Unboxing (the automatic conversion from an object to its primitive data type counterpart)

Yes it does. This is quite what happens for example when you do:

```
'' + { };
```

Which gets you:

```
'[object Object]'
```

Although this doesn't exactly fit "Unboxing".

I think a better example would be to use either a `String` or a `Number`. Since those are the values that actually get boxed.

```
new String('test') + '!!!' // "test!!!"
2 ** (new Number(2)) // 4
2 + (new Number(2)) //4
2 / (new Number(2)) //1
```

Comment: `'' + new Number(42)` will not actually unbox the object. It converts it to a string which is a different mechanism.

Comment: But it does if you do `5 + new Number(42)`. Context is important here.

Comment: Type coercion is still a different mechanism to boxing/unboxing in the Java sense.

Comment: Well, there's at least a definition given by the oracle docs that fits this [behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Maybe `Object` is just a bad example here.

Comment: The compiler converts the type of the value in JavaScript? I didn't know we either had a compiler in JavaScript or that the types changed on stuff like assignment and method calls. (well compiler is an implementation detail, of course. It doesn't really work like the Java compiler)

Comment: That would be an implementation detail for sure... I believe the standard does allow for implementations to even circumvent the intermediary objects.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain the underlying primitive value from an object wrapper is to use the valueOf() method:

```
 const a = Object(false);
 a == false; //true
 a === false //false
 a.valueOf() == false //true
 a.valueOf() === false //true
```

Comment: That is nothing to do with automatic unboxing.